# Create JSON string from javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, string, json, loops, for-loop

I want to create a JSON string from a javascript for loop. This is what I tried to do (which gives me something that looks like a JSON string), but it does not work.

```
var edited = "";
for(var i=1;i<POST.length-1;i++) {
    edited += '"'+POST[i].name+'":"'+POST[i].value+'",';
}
```

It gives me this:

```
"type":"empty","name":"email-address","realname":"Email Address","status":"empty","min":"empty","max":"empty","dependson":"empty",
```

This does not work if I try to convert it into a JSON object later.

Comment: what's your expected result??

Comment: This was my expected result: {"type":"empty","name":"empty","realname":"empty","status":"empty","min":"empty","max":"empty","dependson":"empty","matches":"empty"}. Problem solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two problems:

- You want an object, so the JSON string has to start with `{` and end with `}`.
- There is a trailing `,` which may be recognized as invalid.

It's probably better to use a library, but to correct your code:

- Change `var edited = "";` to `var edited = "{";` to start your JSON string with a `{`
- Add `edited = edited.slice(0, -1);` after the for loop to remove the trailing comma.
- Add `edited += "}";` after the previous statement to end your JSON string with a `}`

Your final code would be:

```
var edited = "{";
for(var i=1;i<POST.length-1;i++) {
    edited += '"'+POST[i].name+'":"'+POST[i].value+'",';
}
edited = edited.slice(0, -1);
edited += "}";
```

Again, it's best to use a library (e.g. `JSON.stringify`) by making an object with a for loop, adding properties by using `POST[i].name` as a key and `POST[i].value` as the value, then using the library to convert the object to JSON.

Also, you are starting with index `1` and ending with index `POST.length-2`, therefore excluding indices `0` (the first value) and `POST.length-1` (the last value). Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 4):

```
//dummy data
var post=[{name:'name1',value:1},{name:'name2',value:2}];

var json=[];
for(var i=0;i<post.length;i++)
{
    var temp={};
    temp[post[i].name]=post[i].value;
   json.push(temp);
}

var stringJson = JSON.stringify(json);


alert(stringJson );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3mYux/

Comment: Thank you. Im getting an error at `json.push({POST[i].name:POST[i].value});`. It say Unexpected Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just build up a hash and do `toString` on the hash? Something like this:

```
var edited = {};
for(var i=0;i<POST.length-1;i++) {    
    edited[POST[i].name] = POST[i].value;
}
```

Or maybe `JSON.stringify` is what you are looking for: http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 0):

You have extra comma in your JSON string. JSON string format: {"JSON": "Hello, World"}

```
var edited = "{";
for(var i=1;i<POST.length-1;i++) {
    edited += '"'+POST[i].name+'":"'+POST[i].value+'",';
}
// remove last comma:
edited = edited.substring(0, edited.length-1) + "}";
```